# Are there satellite TV channels for fans of Extreme Metal?

Tags: metal, symphonic-metal, black-metal

I and my brother are two fans of the extreme metal genre.

We have searched our receiver's channels lists in several satellites (Hotbird, Eutelsat, etc.) but found none of the channels streaming this genre. We observed the channels for hours. Channels like 4Music TV, etc.

Even we didn't find a channel fitting this criterion in [this website](https://lyngsat.com) which has information for all sat channels.

Please introduce me to channels that show extreme metal music videos (preferably not cable TVs).